# How to replace many matches in the text with different values using regexprep in Matlab

Tags: regex, matlab

I'm using the function [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html?s_tid=doc_ta) in Matlab to replace several instances of a pattern with a list of values from a cell array. The idea is to replace the first match with the first value, the second with the next one, and so on. So each match replaced with a *different* value from the cell array.

From the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html?s_tid=doc_ta#btrbo5i-replace) I read that:

> If `replace` is a cell array of N character vectors and `expression` is a single character vector, then regexprep attempts N matches and replacements.

So here is an example of the task I have (for this example let's assume that I know there are only 4 matches):

```
% some text:
str = 'abc s;dlf kudnbv. soergi; abcva/.lge roins.br oianabca/ sergosr toibnsabc';
pattern = '([a][b][c])'; % the patern to match
values = {'111','222','333','444'}; % the cell array 
new_str = regexprep(str,pattern,values) % the actual raplace
```

The result:

```
new_str =
    '111 s;dlf kudnbv. soergi; 111va/.lge roins.br oian111a/ sergosr toibns111'
```

This result is not correct, of course, because all the matches were replaced by the first value in the cell array.

So I googled this problem and found this [explanation](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/404161-regexprep-incorrect-multiple-replacement#comment_575365). Apparently the function `regexprep` execute the replaces one by one, so after the first replacement, the first match that is found is what was the second match originally, and because it is recognized as the first one, it is replaced by the first value in the cell array (111).

I can work around this with a loop that preforms this task with a different value each time:

```
new_str = str;
for k = 1:numel(values)
    new_str = regexprep(new_str,pattern,values(k),'once'); % raplace one value each time
end
```

The result:

```
new_str =
    '111 s;dlf kudnbv. soergi; 222va/.lge roins.br oian333a/ sergosr toibns444'
```

which is exactly what I want.

**My question is how to write the `pattern` or use the `regexprep` in order to achieve the same result without a loop?**
It seems to me that I miss something in how to use this function. I'll also add that my true problem has over 100 matches within the text, so using a pattern like `([a][b][c])(.*)([a][b][c])(.*)([a][b][c])(.*)([a][b][c])` and a replace pattern like `111$2222$4333$6444` (that gives the correct result here) is not really an option.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: By the way, in the loop you might as well use [strrep](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) rather than `regexprep` , probably faster.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness If the pattern is simple as in this example, then you probably right. But my real problem was more complicated, so I needed regex also for finding the correct matches. See my suggestion for an alternative below.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. Good solution!

Comment: Cris's answer is what you are looking for. I was getting confused with the two questions. By the way, I think I figured out the solution for the other question. With `str = 'abc (1,2,3,1,2,3)';
pattern = {'1','2','3'};
values = {'7','8','9'};
new_str = regexprep(str,pattern,values)` the `new_str` is `abc (7,8,9,7,8,9)`

Comment: Although ^ only works for exact matches. Take `str = 'abc (1,2,3)';
pattern = {'\d','\d','\d'};
values = {'7','8','9'};
new_str = regexprep(str,pattern,values)`, the output string is `abc (9,9,9)`, and with the 'once' option `abc (9,2,3)`. This is the behaviour I was referring to in my previous comment, however I guess I misunderstood what you were after.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness is says in the docs: _"If both replace and expression are cell arrays of character vectors, then they must contain the same number of elements. regexprep pairs each replace element with its matching element in expression."_ So you woudn't expect the `pattern = {'\d','\d','\d'}; values = {'7','8','9'};` example to work. However, it works with the `nextStr` solution I worte below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation linked in the question, `regexprep(str,pattern,values)`, with `values` a cell array of strings and `pattern` a single string, applies the search and replace once for each element in `values`. It is thus equivalent to:

```
str = regexprep(str,pattern,values{1});
str = regexprep(str,pattern,values{2});
str = regexprep(str,pattern,values{3});
... etc.
```

After the first replacement, `pattern` is no longer present in `str`, so the second (and subsequent) replacements don't find any matches. That is, each call to `regexprep` will replace *all* matches. In contrast, `regexprep(...,'once')` will replace only the first match.

Thus:

```
str = 'abc s;dlf kudnbv. soergi; abcva/.lge roins.br oianabca/ sergosr toibnsabc abc/abc';
pattern = '([a][b][c])'; % the patern to match
values = {'111','222','333','444'};
new_str = regexprep(str,pattern,values,'once')
```

will do exactly as desired:

```
new_str =
    '111 s;dlf kudnbv. soergi; 222va/.lge roins.br oian333a/ sergosr toibns444 abc/abc'
```

Note I added two more "abc" elements to the end of the string, and note that these did not get replaced. `values` has 4 elements, then only the first 4 matches are replaced.

Comment: Good solution, +1, I think I got mixed up with the two questions.

Comment: Great! this was what I missed in calling the function. Thanks!

Comment: And here I was thinking I was clever when the answer didn't need to be so clever D:

Answer (score 4):

You could make a basic helper string generator and use the command execution replacement token.

For example:

```
classdef strgenerator < handle
    properties
        strs
        ii = 1
    end

    methods
        function self = strgenerator(strs)
            self.strs = strs;
        end

        function outstr = nextstr(self)
            outstr = self.strs{self.ii};

            self.ii = self.ii + 1;
            if self.ii > numel(self.strs)
                self.ii = 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

And

```
str = 'abc s;dlf kudnbv. soergi; abcva/.lge roins.br oianabca/ sergosr toibnsabc';
pattern = '([a][b][c])'; % the patern to match
values = strgenerator({'111','222','333','444'}); % the cell array 
new_str = regexprep(str,pattern,'${values.nextstr()}') % the actual raplace
```

Provides us with:

```
>> SOcode

new_str =

    '111 s;dlf kudnbv. soergi; 222va/.lge roins.br oian333a/ sergosr toibns444'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's interesting, you basically create sort of a 'while' loop within the new object, so it's unseen in the outer code. I must admit I was hoping for a simpler solution, although the end result (the call to `regxprep`)  is quite elegant,

Comment: It doesn't have to be a class, it's just the easiest way to persist the state of the generator. The replacement can be any function as long as it outputs text. I've done [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36181662/replacing-strings-with-regexprep-inside-a-for-loop-matlab/36182554#36182554) in the past with an anonymous function.

Comment: Funny, I just wrote here another implementation for that with a function...

Answer (score 2):

Using @excaza idea, I wrote a simpler implementation, for people (like me) that don't really use OOP in Matlab:

We start with a helper function that remembers the index from the previous call to the function and returns the next cell from its input `strCellArray`:

```
function out = nextStr(strCellArray)
persistent n
    if isempty(n) || n>numel(strCellArray)
        n = 1;
    end
    out = strCellArray{n};
    n = n+1;
end
```

Then we can just write:

```
values = {'111','222','333','444'}; % the cell array 
new_str = regexprep(str,pattern,'${nextStr(values)}'); % execute the command between {...} on every call to the function
clear nextStr % to reset the counter in the function
```

and get the same result:

```
111 s;dlf kudnbv. soergi; 222va/.lge roins.br oian333a/ sergosr toibns444
```

The tricky thing here is to notice that although we only call `regexprep` once, it is actually called N times successively, so the command in the last argument is evaluated N times.

Comment: Neat solution! +1 Although a loop will probably be faster.

Comment: I guess you right, but if speed is not an issue, then this has the advantage of being reusable